# NSArray help for a beginner. Cocos2s / 2d platformer

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, nsmutablearray, collision

I am struggling getting my head around `NSMutableArrays` and need some help.

I am trying to test the collisions of the 'player' and 'coins' littered through the level, ala traditional mario.

I am getting a crash reporting '*** Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x4bf6d0> was mutated while being enumerated.'

I had followed a similar sprite collision method as per: 
http://geekanddad.wordpress.com/2010/06/22/enemies-and-combat-how-to-make-a-tile-based-game-with-cocos2d-part-3/

For some reason if only 1 coin is spawned it all works fine - however if > 1 coin is spawned any coin-collision will throw the crash.

I understand this is a noob issue, and relates to [delete addObject:nuCoin]; - i have looked around and read making a sub array to handle the remove function - however im clearly lost and would appreciate the help, thanks in advance!

```
-(void) coinCollision {

    NSMutableArray *coinsToDelete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *delete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (CCSprite *nuCoin in _coins) {


        CGRect coinRect = CGRectMake((nuCoin.position.x+1) - (nuCoin.contentSize.width/4),
                                     (nuCoin.position.y+5) - (nuCoin.contentSize.height/4),
                                     nuCoin.contentSize.width/3.5,
                                     nuCoin.contentSize.height/7);




    for (CCSprite *Player in _player) {
        CGRect playerRect = CGRectMake(player.position.x - (player.contentSize.width/4),
                                    player.position.y - (player.contentSize.height*.05),
                                    player.contentSize.width*.05,
                                    player.contentSize.height/2);



            if (CGRectIntersectsRect(coinRect, playerRect)) {

                [coinsToDelete addObject:nuCoin];}


        }


    for (CCSprite *nuCoin in coinsToDelete) {

        [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"Coin.mp3"];
        [_coins removeObject:nuCoin];

        [delete addObject:nuCoin];
        [map removeChild:nuCoin cleanup:YES];

    }

    }

    [delete release];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add or remove objects to/from mutable arrays inside a fast enumeration `for(...in...)` loop. You'll need to develop some othe logic to make this work (e. g. store the indices of the objects to be deleted, or otherwise mark them as deletable and after finishing the for loop, delete all of them in one step.)

Example:

```
NSMutableArray *markedAsDeletee = [NSMutableArray array];
for (CCSprite *sprite in array)
{
    if (/* decide wheteher this sprite should be deleted */)
        [markedAsDeletee addObject:sprite];
}

[array removeObjectsInArray:markedAsDeletee];
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, - I am at such a noob level that whilst I understand what your saying, cant picture the code. Could you/someone please provide an example? Thanks :)

Comment: @user1593384 sure, but can you think a bit about it anyways? This is such an obvious-to-do task.

Comment: :) i have been thinking about it all day - and the worst part is I understand it's meant to be easy. its so frustrating im missing this basic understanding.. /learning :)

Comment: @user1593384 just try to think algorithmically. Consider what you want to achieve and *how* you could make it into smaller chunks that the language you're using can interpret. :)

Comment: @user1593384 ah, and I'd appreciate marking my answer as accepted if it was really useful. Thanks!

Comment: Ok Ill go and work on it and see if i can do it - thanks for your time. ill come back to report hopefully good news otherwise ill be needing more help :)